# Apache ToLower on all Wordpress pages (not PDF/CSS/JS)

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having issues performing a 301 redirection of URLs that contain capitals to lowercase, excluding static files (PDF/CSS/JS/JPEG/JPG/PNG/WEBP...etc). For example:

`https://www.example.com/Page/` would become
`https://www.example.com/page/`

but `https://www.example.com/Clear_IMAGE.png` would not be changed.

In my VirtualHost conf file:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

In my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lc:$1} !^(pdf|js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)
```

However this doesn't have any effect on my URLs.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lc:$1} !^(pdf|js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)
> ```

You say this "doesn't have any effect", however, this is syntactically invalid ("bad flags argument") and *should* break with a 500 Internal Server Error!? If not then there maybe another more fundamental problem?

However, this has other issues:

- In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.
- You should only lowercase the URL (ie. call the `lc` rewrite map) if the source request contains an uppercase letter, otherwise you will naturally get a redirect loop.
- The regex `^(pdf|js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)` is matching a string that *starts* with those characters. You need to (negate) match a string that ends with dot + file extension.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(pdf|js|css|png|jpe?g|webp)$ [NC]
RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

Note that this must go near the top of the `.htaccess` file *before* the WordPress code block. ie. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `[A-Z]` simply tests that there is at least 1 uppercase letter in the URL-path.

The *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) excludes URLs that end with any of the stated file extensions (case-insensitive).

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable already includes the slash prefix, so this is omitted from the start of the *substitution* string.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

Instead of excluding a (ever growing) list of known file types, you could instead simply exclude any request that looks like it has a file-extension. (Assuming your WordPress page URLs don't have a file-extension.) eg. a dot followed by 2 to 4 letters/digits at the end of the URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
:
```

The `NC` flag is not necessary here since the `\w` shorthand character class already contains both upper and lowercase letters.